# How to read from a zip file within zip file in Python?

Tags: python, file, zip, unzip

I have a file that I want to read that is itself zipped within a zip archive. For example, parent.zip contains child.zip, which contains child.txt. I am having trouble reading child.zip.  Can anyone correct my code?

I assume that I need to create child.zip as a file-like object and then open it with a second instance of zipfile, but being new to python my zipfile.ZipFile(zfile.open(name)) is silly.  It raises a zipfile.BadZipfile: "File is not a zip file" on (independently validated) child.zip

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile("parent.zip", "r") as zfile:
    for name in zfile.namelist():
        if re.search(r'\.zip$', name) is not None:
            # We have a zip within a zip
            with **zipfile.ZipFile(zfile.open(name))** as zfile2:
                    for name2 in zfile2.namelist():
                        # Now we can extract
                        logging.info( "Found internal internal file: " + name2)
                        print "Processing code goes here"
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

When you use the `.open()` call on a `ZipFile` instance you indeed get an open file handle. However, to *read* a zip file, the `ZipFile` class needs a little more. It needs to be able to *seek* on that file, and the object returned by `.open()` is not seekable in your case. Only Python 3 (3.2 and up) produces a `ZipExFile` object that supports seeking (provided the underlying file handle for the outer zip file is seekable, and nothing is trying to write to the `ZipFile` object).

The workaround is to read the whole zip entry into memory using `.read()`, store it in a `BytesIO` object (an in-memory file that *is* seekable) and feed that to `ZipFile`:

```
from io import BytesIO

# ...
        zfiledata = BytesIO(zfile.read(name))
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zfiledata) as zfile2:
```

or, in the context of your example:

```
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO

with zipfile.ZipFile("parent.zip", "r") as zfile:
    for name in zfile.namelist():
        if re.search(r'\.zip$', name) is not None:
            # We have a zip within a zip
            zfiledata = BytesIO(zfile.read(name))
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zfiledata) as zfile2:
                for name2 in zfile2.namelist():
                    # Now we can extract
                    logging.info( "Found internal internal file: " + name2)
                    print "Processing code goes here"
```

Answer (score 15):

To get this to work with python33 (under windows but that might be unrelevant) i had to do :

```
 import zipfile, re, io
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r') as zfile:
        for name in zfile.namelist():
            if re.search(r'\.zip$', name) != None:
                zfiledata = io.BytesIO(zfile.read(name))
                with zipfile.ZipFile(zfiledata) as zfile2:
                    for name2 in zfile2.namelist():
                        print(name2)
```

cStringIO does not exist so i used io.BytesIO